# How can I get a DOM from a file with Rust?

Tags: rust, minidom

I want to read a XML file with Rust to get a DOM. I'm learning Rust and I tried [minidom](https://docs.rs/minidom/0.11.0/minidom/index.html).

With [minidom](https://docs.rs/minidom/0.11.0/minidom/index.html) I can get a DOM from a "String/str".

But how do I get a DOM from a file with Rust?

Comment: What did you try? Did you look at Rust's [`std::fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) or [`std::fs::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html)?

Comment: I wonder if you have to make the detour with string instead of reading "somehow" directly from the file

Answer (score 2):

The other answers use `std::fs::read_to_string`, which duplicates the content of file into the memory.
There is indeed a solution that avoids this intermediate `String`:

```rust
use minidom::quick_xml;
use minidom::Element;

let mut reader = quick_xml::Reader::from_file("example.xml").unwrap();
let element = Element::from_reader(&mut reader);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the examples in [std::fs::file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html)

```
let mut file = File::open("foo.xml")?;
let mut contents = String::new();
file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;
```

Now you should use contents as a parameter for the minimum parser.

Comment: This can fit in a single line, e.g. `let content = std::fs::read_to_string("foo.xml")?;`. But there also is a solution that does not even require copying the whole file to RAM (see my answer)